# Does Google-firebase allows data handling logic

Tags: ios, firebase, mobile, server-side

I have a requirement to write data processing logic at Server-side and based on the outcome of that logic to send notifications to multiple iphones. I want to use Google Firebase to store data. But I am not sure if Google Firebase allows to write some programming logic at Firebase side to manipulate those data. Can someone please advise if I can write code logic at Google Firebase? T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run server-side logic in response to events happening in your Firebase project, you'll want to look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). With Cloud Functions you write code that runs on Google's servers and that is called in response to activity in your Firebase project, or calls from your client-side app.

The documentation has a page with [common use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases), which includes [sending notifications to users when something relevant happens in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).